# Extract year from UNIX timestamp with SQL

Tags: sql, time, timestamp, extract

I have a column called tidpunkt in the database that stores the dates in timestamp formats. How do I extract only the year with SQL? I still want the extracted year to be in timestamp.

I've tried like this:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM tidpunkt) as tidpunkt FROM ringupp
```

But it does not work. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT YEAR(tidpunkt) as tidpunkt FROM ringupp
```

Do this

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(tidpunkt , '%Y') AS tidpunkt FROM ringupp
```

**MySQL** `FROM_UNIXTIME()` returns a date /datetime from a version of unix_timestamp. The return value is in ‘YYYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS’ .

See [**DOCUMENTATION**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) . Also see this [**Example**](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-from_unixtime-function.php)

Comment: @m hasan: It does not work. Nothing is returned.. The timestamp in the database looks like this: 1370601583

Comment: ok , so your timestamp is in unix format..check edited answer

Comment: @m hasan: Thank you very much. How do I get the rows that has the year 2014? SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(tidpunkt, '%Y') AS tidpunkt WHERE tidpunkt == "CURRENT YEAR IN TIMESTAMP"; I dont know how to get the current year in the SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

if you require 4 digit year

```
SELECT DATEPART('yyyy',tidpunkt) as tidpunkt FROM ringupp
```

and if 2 digit year is required:

```
SELECT DATEPART('yy',tidpunkt) as tidpunkt FROM ringupp
```

Documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

date_format is your friend with mysql
see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( tidpunkt, '%Y' ) as tidpunkt FROM ringupp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM tidpunkt) FROM ringupp
```